# Tomcat not deploying latest WAR file changes in Windows

Tags: java, tomcat

I've developed a Web application and created WAR file and deployed in Server Tomcat under webapps.

Then I have stopped the shutdown service and started the startup service under bin folder. But still older changes are visible. The latest changes of the war file are not visible.

I've checked whether the changes are available in WAR after extracting it. They are available

What is missing in the flow?

Comment: Try cleaning your browser cache, make sure the war file is deployed with no errors... Check $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.latestdate.log for deployment info

Comment: Try deleting the directory that is named same as your project after shutdown and then use startup service.

Comment: I tried both. There were no errors in deploying

Comment: @cootload, U mean 1. Delete the WAR file. 2. Shutdown 3. Startup 4. Again place the WAR fuke

Comment: are you using hot deploy or you deploy it using the manager app?

Comment: 1. Shutdown 2. Delete the Directory/ Folder and the war file named as your project 3. Copy new war 4. Startup

Comment: @cooltoad, first of all, there is no directory under webapp, there is just a WAR file, I followed your steps.. But still not updating

Comment: @MaVRoSCy, I'm just pasting the WAR file under webapp.

Comment: delete temporary files on server.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal, No use :(

Comment: Either you're interacting with a different Tomcat instance or the webapps is configured to be in a different folder.

Comment: No. Its the only one tomcat instance, but the folder should be created right? There is no folder too

Comment: @cooltoad, I just found that under tomcat, we have wtpwebapps folder, there I see my project folder. Should I delete that

Comment: @cooltoad, I have copied my project folder into wtpwebapps and restarted the startup.. and it works now

Comment: Good to know! Perhaps add an answer yourself and get to know the config to the different webapps folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the latest changes only when I keep war file under webapps, and the project directory under wtpwebapps.